# Website scales on Apple-devices but not on Android-devices

Tags: html, web, responsive, meta

Currently I am creating my own website and last week I worked on making the website responsive. I tried to make the website responsive for mobile devices and I thought that I fixed the problem, in HTML I added the following line:

```
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

But then I found out that it only works on Apple-devices but not on Android-devices. Do I need to add another line to fix the problem for Android-devices? Or change the line which I already have? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could also try responsive design framework of `Bootstrap`

Comment: Is it something like media queries?

Comment: What width is the content of your website? iirc if you tell it to be in pixels ("1000px" similar) it will not scale properly, but using percent ("100%") works

Comment: I only work with percentages, on iPhone/iPad the responsive website works but not on a Samsung smartphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you were trying to make your website responsive to all devices, I putforth this information:

`Bootstrap` is a front-end framework for designing websites and web applications. Using Bootstrap framework you can design websites that can work in all devices ranging from Desktops to Mobiles.

All you have to do is download the framework and include it in your website and a little code could help.

You can download the framework here,
[Bootstrap Download Page](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) and then get some tutorials [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp)

Hope this helps.